# where condition is not working with lumen and mongodb

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel, lumen

I am using

```
"jenssegers/mongodb": "3.2.*"
```

my query is like below,

```
$query= DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('folder_master')
                ->where('email_account_id',1)->get();
```

it is not giving me any result though there is value present in database.

if I am using query as below

```
$query= DB::connection('mongodb')->collection('folder_master')->get();
```

then it is giving me all the records but where condition is not working.

my expected result is below,

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [_id] => MongoDB\BSON\ObjectId Object
                (
                    [oid] => 5bea89ac19f043251000347d
                )

            [0] => Array
                (
                    [folder_name] => Archive
                    [status] => Active
                    [primary_folder] => 0
                    [email_account_id] => 1
                    [created_at] => Array
                        (
                            [date] => 2018-11-13 08:22:04.000000
                            [timezone_type] => 3
                            [timezone] => UTC
                        )

                    [created_by] => 0
                )

        )
)
```

is there any issue while storing in database ????

here is the json which is stored in mongodb

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bea89ac19f043251000347d"), 
    "0" : {
        "folder_name" : "Archive", 
        "status" : "Active", 
        "primary_folder" : NumberInt(0), 
        "email_account_id" : NumberInt(1), 
        "created_at" : {
            "date" : "2018-11-13 08:22:04.000000", 
            "timezone_type" : NumberInt(3), 
            "timezone" : "UTC"
        }, 
        "created_by" : NumberInt(0)
    }
}
```

please help me to resolve this type of issue

Comment: Show the document you expect to match and the value of `$emailAccountId` you are supplying. If it "returns nothing" then the two values are actually different.

Comment: Can you try actually showing the JSON appearance of the data as viewed from the [`mongo` shell](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/mongo/) please? It might "appear" here that your document structure has some problems, but that might just be an artifact of dumping PHP Data structures. Or it could be the result of bad code writing an errant structure. So the JSON form would make the picture clearer to a wider audience.

Comment: I have update json(in my question) which is stored in mongodb, please look into it.

Comment: Thought so. Looks like some other code broke your document. Everything is under the key `"0"` so it's `where('0.email_account_id',1)` to match this document. However that's surely a result of bad code and the `"0"` should not be there. So what you need to correct is whatever code is responsible for writing the data, and not the query.

Comment: ok, let me correct this,

Comment: it is working , thanks. please add above in answer